# Production-ready disk deduplication for KVM (Linux)?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, deduplication

Multiple Windows VMs, all of them with identical software installed (they're clones in fact) that I have to run for administrative+licensing reasons, give me a headache storage-wise. KVM on Linux runs great but ext4 does not provide any features re de-duplication.

There's LessFS and it seems nice but is anyone running it in production without major problems?

If not LessFS, then the question is: is there *production-ready* disk de-duplication filesystem that I could use for KVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into **[ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org)**. That will deduplicate all day long...

You'll need a lot of RAM and may find that this may not be worth the effort (you could have sized appropriately for your needs), but it does work.